# Casting group of two polygons with rgeo returns nil

Tags: geos, ruby, rgeos

Here's an array of 2 polygons I'm trying to cast into a multipolygon (wkt string format). The polygons are in a linear CRS, SRID:3361

```
["POLYGON ((990863.9961167622 709913.6373089257, 990983.9977276697 709966.5670872123, 991064.1307013977 709990.2012079275, 991146.2737451008 710010.1306932919, 991224.1514265039 710020.369058837, 991310.9681048155 710024.8599556057, 991574.3975293359 710008.025651529, 991999.4023303369 709975.0850933588, 992154.4225144977 709963.1922065137, 992204.1757263432 709959.4110842252, 992892.4955291526 709906.0192916376, 992883.1769682257 710013.7026255019, 992866.3715350745 710068.1160970348, 992829.5366622966 710161.7575079885, 992643.9076696819 710347.5367306554, 992572.9440377987 710429.5330878275, 992505.6504616569 710502.6754820758, 992457.2268332299 710585.7689384365, 992439.8380312523 710650.3937726512, 992433.3054453724 710674.264473755, 992424.5742143014 710752.8080122116, 992425.2630710491 710764.7985821898, 992428.9643398577 710832.7507346236, 992452.3758639012 710927.3714580169, 992477.8686107747 710982.611901817, 992529.3111909343 711059.9523994623, 992637.3851428869 711167.8734148253, 992668.1714655088 711198.5551665452, 992761.1025349424 711289.4897823029, 992819.2971695957 711368.7981065831, 992857.9670017619 711455.6494812274, 992881.0731587668 711550.2805268113, 992884.3748202203 711643.7267144972, 992872.1485259928 711736.5787666875, 992866.6323450541 711763.6929670484, 992859.7959934338 711787.573297175, 992840.4799833929 711839.5193056861, 992825.7449470464 711873.1174722008, 992813.0783914325 711895.3646362422, 992782.9762090456 711990.2466283205, 992777.4232958009 712054.1276171772, 992777.2675031944 712134.5799575929, 992779.5654114062 712215.6818007032, 992778.4642658049 712276.1439098659, 992779.8634687028 712338.7098724722, 992789.3679275116 712464.3544296541, 992787.8230790426 712520.462496864, 992901.9842563535 712514.9800284533, 992916.0355089244 712829.7672889738, 992916.0432820335 713142.8207769113, 992913.7393852634 713184.7566489829, 992924.7518709908 713518.5700722353, 992960.8418994583 713515.5923134589, 992968.2483172219 713528.4593531466, 992982.4660765656 713545.112040343, 993073.6383353218 713619.3589296789, 993118.4996476307 713662.330075848, 993146.2455441204 713693.1096626577, 993240.848357749 713826.9458020271, 993249.9133492103 713844.1277411825, 993259.7954304608 713877.3004079086, 993345.4330991866 713873.8261055837, 993533.7270361778 714094.2069258634, 993836.2839015241 714084.8723591259, 993847.0940241282 714346.2532488945, 994289.8922129284 714320.0520425317, 994760.1215144501 714305.3551180988, 995226.8454146484 714295.1455212078, 995670.4270350334 714274.3987142374, 995835.5902389007 714266.5670771812, 995881.4134799222 714330.2600546797, 996049.68901713 714685.9812829013, 996505.6363921547 714671.7670744457, 996530.8591699917 715108.8710003135, 996855.5268146558 715068.6451267638, 997183.524800065 715027.952447736, 997679.4303736924 714970.2527712836, 997842.9360121351 714939.1877452713, 998032.3980925721 714921.1273444555, 998107.658926187 714916.5412822802, 998153.5624496548 714906.7038405545, 998251.3227126903 714854.4420526164, 998388.7582055425 714749.5886977918, 998486.4971993824 714639.4500673239, 998525.5446955595 714624.371973667, 998594.3947376116 714609.4350840027, 998927.8995356079 714579.1413108781, 998971.301824288 714576.6651461165, 999213.4574904437 714551.8357741621, 999323.1969768881 714541.4211487508, 999716.0561701497 714493.9554957018, 1000054.1898888611 714418.0244293762, 1000089.2286396839 714410.7201029925, 1000085.2249326878 714313.6561335874, 1000050.015137732 714134.226590919, 1000034.2775848118 714136.5481321659, 1000011.5500681093 713852.6133484959, 1000002.392658444 713631.9487497256, 1000065.2718612577 713629.9458690294, 1000016.7922058875 713482.6084344113, 1000002.1855430695 713491.8100068349, 1000001.6849139313 713485.6377869908, 999999.0167722187 713459.1498076732, 999962.7894572295 713066.4410232315, 999958.87695872 712848.1574872587, 999973.5882131363 712756.321436856, 999995.8716270756 712491.701966677, 1000017.3053598094 712343.5937126086, 1000010.8390458741 712236.0516366494, 1000028.7724073376 712197.6231545407, 1000035.0616472174 712185.0462667545, 1000336.8065496271 711328.3780526607, 1000303.4682083512 711341.4521304993, 1000277.1895471581 711347.021157001, 1000237.2054084942 711351.9343936025, 1000147.6576677439 711356.9703043719, 999969.9772028917 711363.7213542048, 999907.8775150771 711361.6953613729, 1000040.024757326 711023.3219226944, 1000157.3508947502 710715.9984126444, 1000265.3337294774 710401.6927849171, 1000192.8272737804 710378.5205496156, 1000111.6104260356 710005.4457985226, 1000099.1128435526 709947.2376280092, 1000078.91254184 709857.2418226056, 1000110.1473574076 709768.5199573763, 999987.9537476684 709216.5638555621, 999789.7989997756 709230.1559062654, 999336.979715984 709268.6093156412, 999165.690557258 709275.8888614874, 999093.9434148058 709286.1841316596, 998975.5724131042 709303.0624030803, 998812.1614820304 709347.5861462927, 998643.837096578 709419.2044248215, 998530.2722500743 709472.3323336822, 998521.0274151277 709382.7160117374, 998493.404054664 709136.4321102834, 998275.4553937428 709149.2089586717, 997760.9884452621 709180.9153753119, 997290.2240783992 709209.778643122, 996947.2586291947 709231.2898089463, 996957.9136461994 709364.9063833423, 996638.5984384521 709393.6738532373, 996399.0568827817 709415.8902002193, 996402.1934104317 709456.9236896214, 996017.5979791152 709479.4116270983, 995964.1630157694 709482.2123858188, 995964.4247483473 709452.3548670281, 995856.4053840187 709488.5705084121, 995549.5961679708 709508.9409315598, 995099.5661549673 709539.357901603, 994653.1590699845 709568.937115338, 994438.2754770508 709582.3707314484, 994167.3164922566 709601.606536923, 993730.5627459398 709628.7058220214, 993708.0337839914 709637.4360431305, 993659.3655983148 709656.104563463, 993335.510791566 709675.9509659848, 993011.3522560379 709695.8101852848, 992955.8031850796 709699.0479861686, 992834.9945596352 709706.1992105845, 992451.9573689091 709729.7729781921, 991566.4898259126 709799.6982590985, 991551.019283777 709800.9233681606, 990858.8536185692 709763.1000773438, 990863.9961167622 709913.6373089257))", "POLYGON ((994184.5444268881 710034.9604690579, 995588.4287257312 710057.3603710752, 995567.475658347 709744.6142989218, 995960.2237629025 709720.4036916478, 996028.8249934851 709716.3900188167, 996420.6739997797 709692.5780370348, 996871.7066796231 709665.0600338635, 996981.5789749525 709658.2737395772, 997295.2682379928 709643.8860277529, 997785.761804787 709614.0289438027, 998127.2994825988 709586.0202700456, 998274.2170492779 709558.3997143694, 998438.5514675695 709504.7431852733, 998519.7489476844 709552.3870192909, 998543.8507361393 709964.7735390866, 998577.8214527883 710543.5634810682, 998632.0304747507 711461.3330311812, 998293.1795789987 711477.6027504519, 997867.7366872035 711505.7404232696, 997391.6434437606 711538.0493750903, 996938.0212160782 711559.8193055987, 996356.4000301149 711591.875708205, 996055.2201466302 711606.9653884522, 995612.7810177513 711626.5770288671, 994608.2576289732 711690.0345619402, 994215.2531717191 711724.4636099562, 994184.5444268881 710034.9604690579))"]
```

I've listed the polygons in their wkt text format, but in the program they're in the form of ruby objects so I can run methods on them. Heres a text dump of the objects themselves

```
polygons = [#<RGeo::Geos::CAPIPolygonImpl:0x3fc05a8a3ea0 "POLYGON ((990863.9961167622 709913.6373089257, 990983.9977276697 709966.5670872123, 991064.1307013977 709990.2012079275, 991146.2737451008 710010.1306932919, 991224.1514265039 710020.369058837, 991310.9681048155 710024.8599556057, 991574.3975293359 710008.025651529, 991999.4023303369 709975.0850933588, 992154.4225144977 709963.1922065137, 992204.1757263432 709959.4110842252, 992892.4955291526 709906.0192916376, 992883.1769682257 710013.7026255019, 992866.3715350745 710068.1160970348, 992829.5366622966 710161.7575079885, 992643.9076696819 710347.5367306554, 992572.9440377987 710429.5330878275, 992505.6504616569 710502.6754820758, 992457.2268332299 710585.7689384365, 992439.8380312523 710650.3937726512, 992433.3054453724 710674.264473755, 992424.5742143014 710752.8080122116, 992425.2630710491 710764.7985821898, 992428.9643398577 710832.7507346236, 992452.3758639012 710927.3714580169, 992477.8686107747 710982.611901817, 992529.3111909343 711059.9523994623, 992637.3851428869 711167.8734148253, 992668.1714655088 711198.5551665452, 992761.1025349424 711289.4897823029, 992819.2971695957 711368.7981065831, 992857.9670017619 711455.6494812274, 992881.0731587668 711550.2805268113, 992884.3748202203 711643.7267144972, 992872.1485259928 711736.5787666875, 992866.6323450541 711763.6929670484, 992859.7959934338 711787.573297175, 992840.4799833929 711839.5193056861, 992825.7449470464 711873.1174722008, 992813.0783914325 711895.3646362422, 992782.9762090456 711990.2466283205, 992777.4232958009 712054.1276171772, 992777.2675031944 712134.5799575929, 992779.5654114062 712215.6818007032, 992778.4642658049 712276.1439098659, 992779.8634687028 712338.7098724722, 992789.3679275116 712464.3544296541, 992787.8230790426 712520.462496864, 992901.9842563535 712514.9800284533, 992916.0355089244 712829.7672889738, 992916.0432820335 713142.8207769113, 992913.7393852634 713184.7566489829, 992924.7518709908 713518.5700722353, 992960.8418994583 713515.5923134589, 992968.2483172219 713528.4593531466, 992982.4660765656 713545.112040343, 993073.6383353218 713619.3589296789, 993118.4996476307 713662.330075848, 993146.2455441204 713693.1096626577, 993240.848357749 713826.9458020271, 993249.9133492103 713844.1277411825, 993259.7954304608 713877.3004079086, 993345.4330991866 713873.8261055837, 993533.7270361778 714094.2069258634, 993836.2839015241 714084.8723591259, 993847.0940241282 714346.2532488945, 994289.8922129284 714320.0520425317, 994760.1215144501 714305.3551180988, 995226.8454146484 714295.1455212078, 995670.4270350334 714274.3987142374, 995835.5902389007 714266.5670771812, 995881.4134799222 714330.2600546797, 996049.68901713 714685.9812829013, 996505.6363921547 714671.7670744457, 996530.8591699917 715108.8710003135, 996855.5268146558 715068.6451267638, 997183.524800065 715027.952447736, 997679.4303736924 714970.2527712836, 997842.9360121351 714939.1877452713, 998032.3980925721 714921.1273444555, 998107.658926187 714916.5412822802, 998153.5624496548 714906.7038405545, 998251.3227126903 714854.4420526164, 998388.7582055425 714749.5886977918, 998486.4971993824 714639.4500673239, 998525.5446955595 714624.371973667, 998594.3947376116 714609.4350840027, 998927.8995356079 714579.1413108781, 998971.301824288 714576.6651461165, 999213.4574904437 714551.8357741621, 999323.1969768881 714541.4211487508, 999716.0561701497 714493.9554957018, 1000054.1898888611 714418.0244293762, 1000089.2286396839 714410.7201029925, 1000085.2249326878 714313.6561335874, 1000050.015137732 714134.226590919, 1000034.2775848118 714136.5481321659, 1000011.5500681093 713852.6133484959, 1000002.392658444 713631.9487497256, 1000065.2718612577 713629.9458690294, 1000016.7922058875 713482.6084344113, 1000002.1855430695 713491.8100068349, 1000001.6849139313 713485.6377869908, 999999.0167722187 713459.1498076732, 999962.7894572295 713066.4410232315, 999958.87695872 712848.1574872587, 999973.5882131363 712756.321436856, 999995.8716270756 712491.701966677, 1000017.3053598094 712343.5937126086, 1000010.8390458741 712236.0516366494, 1000028.7724073376 712197.6231545407, 1000035.0616472174 712185.0462667545, 1000336.8065496271 711328.3780526607, 1000303.4682083512 711341.4521304993, 1000277.1895471581 711347.021157001, 1000237.2054084942 711351.9343936025, 1000147.6576677439 711356.9703043719, 999969.9772028917 711363.7213542048, 999907.8775150771 711361.6953613729, 1000040.024757326 711023.3219226944, 1000157.3508947502 710715.9984126444, 1000265.3337294774 710401.6927849171, 1000192.8272737804 710378.5205496156, 1000111.6104260356 710005.4457985226, 1000099.1128435526 709947.2376280092, 1000078.91254184 709857.2418226056, 1000110.1473574076 709768.5199573763, 999987.9537476684 709216.5638555621, 999789.7989997756 709230.1559062654, 999336.979715984 709268.6093156412, 999165.690557258 709275.8888614874, 999093.9434148058 709286.1841316596, 998975.5724131042 709303.0624030803, 998812.1614820304 709347.5861462927, 998643.837096578 709419.2044248215, 998530.2722500743 709472.3323336822, 998521.0274151277 709382.7160117374, 998493.404054664 709136.4321102834, 998275.4553937428 709149.2089586717, 997760.9884452621 709180.9153753119, 997290.2240783992 709209.778643122, 996947.2586291947 709231.2898089463, 996957.9136461994 709364.9063833423, 996638.5984384521 709393.6738532373, 996399.0568827817 709415.8902002193, 996402.1934104317 709456.9236896214, 996017.5979791152 709479.4116270983, 995964.1630157694 709482.2123858188, 995964.4247483473 709452.3548670281, 995856.4053840187 709488.5705084121, 995549.5961679708 709508.9409315598, 995099.5661549673 709539.357901603, 994653.1590699845 709568.937115338, 994438.2754770508 709582.3707314484, 994167.3164922566 709601.606536923, 993730.5627459398 709628.7058220214, 993708.0337839914 709637.4360431305, 993659.3655983148 709656.104563463, 993335.510791566 709675.9509659848, 993011.3522560379 709695.8101852848, 992955.8031850796 709699.0479861686, 992834.9945596352 709706.1992105845, 992451.9573689091 709729.7729781921, 991566.4898259126 709799.6982590985, 991551.019283777 709800.9233681606, 990858.8536185692 709763.1000773438, 990863.9961167622 709913.6373089257))">, #<RGeo::Geos::CAPIPolygonImpl:0x3fc05a831648 "POLYGON ((994184.5444268881 710034.9604690579, 995588.4287257312 710057.3603710752, 995567.475658347 709744.6142989218, 995960.2237629025 709720.4036916478, 996028.8249934851 709716.3900188167, 996420.6739997797 709692.5780370348, 996871.7066796231 709665.0600338635, 996981.5789749525 709658.2737395772, 997295.2682379928 709643.8860277529, 997785.761804787 709614.0289438027, 998127.2994825988 709586.0202700456, 998274.2170492779 709558.3997143694, 998438.5514675695 709504.7431852733, 998519.7489476844 709552.3870192909, 998543.8507361393 709964.7735390866, 998577.8214527883 710543.5634810682, 998632.0304747507 711461.3330311812, 998293.1795789987 711477.6027504519, 997867.7366872035 711505.7404232696, 997391.6434437606 711538.0493750903, 996938.0212160782 711559.8193055987, 996356.4000301149 711591.875708205, 996055.2201466302 711606.9653884522, 995612.7810177513 711626.5770288671, 994608.2576289732 711690.0345619402, 994215.2531717191 711724.4636099562, 994184.5444268881 710034.9604690579))">]
```

Anyway, I'm using this factory to try to cast them into multipolygons

```
f= RGeo::Geos.factory(:srid => 3361)
```

The error looks like this:

```
f.multi_polygon(polygons)
#=> nil
```

I've run this operation before and it worked.

Comment: just guessing but if I adding some tiny buffers to the polygons they'd probably behave as expected